# Puppet not passing exe switches on windows

Tags: windows, puppet

I am trying to install `vlc` to my lab of 150 window computers using puppet. I am following [this guide](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/writing.html#packagepackage) and have set up my manifest as:

```
node 'node.domain.tld' {

package { "VLC media player 2.1.3":
 ensure   => "2.1.3",
 source   => "\\\\server\\puppet$\\vlc-2.1.3.exe",
 install_options => ['/L=1033 /S']
}
```

Running a `puppet agent -t --debug` shows that this command is being run:

```
cmd.exe /c start "puppet-install" /w \\server\puppet$\vlc-2.1.3.exe "/L=1033 /S"
```

This brings up the windows installer for VLC (but doesn't install silently) when `puppet agent` runs. When I run the command this way (without quotes), it installs silently as intended.

```
cmd.exe /c start "puppet-install" /w \\server\puppet$\vlc-2.1.3.exe /L=1033 /S
```

I came across [this bug](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/18295) which appears to be resolved in version `3.3.0`. Both the puppet master and agent in my environment are version `3.4.3`.

Am I going about this the wrong way to install VLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was told to change `install_options => ['/L=1033 /S']` to `install_options => ['/L=1033', '/S']`

This appears to have solved the problem. Apparently I was sending both switches as one command instead of two separate commands.